# Property of AVL tree

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

I’m doing some exercises about AVL tree
The following two question belong are both false

1. The absolute value of height difference of any subtrees on the same level is at most one

Isn’t it a property of AVL tree?

2. A deletion needs at most two rotation operations to preserve an AVL tree to be a height-balanced tree

As I know the most operation when del/insert a node is double rotations.

Where are the wrong points?
I’m not native speaker, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By absolute value of height difference, do you mean difference between any two leaves of the sub-trees?

If yes, you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28966528/11101571

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean about Q1 , thanks. I found [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/how-many-rotations-after-avl-insertion-and-deletion)  about Q2 , maybe the answer is wrong